How can I use cache image when using bootBuildImage on spring boot project?
I am considering introducing buildpacks to a project that uses Spring Boot.
Most of the operations seem to work without any issues. However, one problem is that the build time has increased.
Currently, I am running the bootBuildImage task through GitHub Actions. To improve the build time, I applied launchCache and buildCache settings, but I didn't see a significant effect.
After checking the buildpacks documentation, I noticed that there is a cache-image option available: https://buildpacks.io/docs/for-app-developers/how-to/build-inputs/use-cache-image/
I think this could be a good solution, but I am wondering if there is a way to set the cache-image option in the Spring Boot Gradle plugin.
Could someone please guide me on how to configure the cache-image option in the Spring Boot Gradle plugin when using buildpacks? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!
Below is my trial
    bootBuildImage {
        builder = "paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:0.4.292"
        buildpacks.set(
            listOf(
                "gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/amazon-corretto:8.4.2",
                "urn:cnb:builder:paketo-buildpacks/java"
            )
        )
        environment.set(
            mapOf(
                "BP_DATADOG_ENABLED" to "true"
            )
        )
        buildCache {
            bind {
                source.set("/tmp/cache-${rootProject.name}.build")
            }
        }
        launchCache {
            bind {
                source.set("/tmp/cache-${rootProject.name}.launch")
            }
        }
    }


I'm looking tor the exact same thing... Did any of the caches in your trial help? buildCache  launchCache

Not worked… because of job priority, I have not tried something for that.
